# REACT (axios) Modal Window prepopulated for PUT method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jsx

I'm making a full CRUD functional website and now I'm a bit confused to make update (put) function with React, input fields in Modal Window should be prepopulated when it opens (as we are editing it), how to make it possible? I'm new in React, that's why I'm sorry for my messy code, here is my code:

```
class StylePage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            show: false,
            styles: [],
            nameEn: '',
            nameRu: '',
            id: '',
    };
    this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
    this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this);
    }
    async componentDidMount(){
        axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/styles/")
        .then(res => {
            const styles = res.data;
            this.setState({styles});
        })
    }
    
    showModal = () => {
        this.setState({show: true})
    }

    hideModal = () => {
        this.setState({show: false})
    }
    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    }
    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        const style = {
            nameEn: this.state.nameEn,
            nameRu: this.state.nameRu,
        };

        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/styles/', style)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
        }).catch((err) => {console.log(err.response)
        console.log(err.message)});
    }

    handleUpdate = (id, event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const style = {
            id: this.state.id,
            nameEn: this.state.nameEn,
            nameRu: this.state.nameRu,
        }
        axios.put(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/styles/${id}/`, style)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
            <div className='row p-1'>
                <h5 className='col-2'>Styles</h5>
                <div className='col-7'></div>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>
        Add
      </Button>

      <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.hideModal}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Adding/Editing style</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <Form onSubmit={this.state.id ? this.handleUpdate : this.handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
              <Form.Label>Style (en)</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                defaultValue={this.state.nameEn}
                name='nameEn'
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              <Form.Label>Style (ru) </Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                name='nameRu'
                defaultValue={this.state.nameRu}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button variant="primary" type='submit' onClick={this.hideModal}>
            {this.state.id ? "Save updates": "Add New"}
          </Button>
          </Form>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
                
            </div>
            <table className='table'>
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope='col'>English naming</th>
                            <th scope='col'>Russian naming</th>
                        </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.state.styles.map(style => 
                        <tr key={style.id}>
                            <td>{style.nameEn}</td>
                            <td>{style.nameRu}</td>
                             <td><button className='btn btn-warning' onClick={(event)=>this.handleUpdate(style.id, event)}>Update</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        )}
                        </tbody>
            </table>
            
    </>
        )
    }
}
```

I'm a bit confused with taking an *id*, giving it to *Form* in Modal and perform function. Could you give an advice how to make correct *handleUpdate* function and connect it with *Modal* and *update button* properly. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Pass the id and event to the handleUpdate function:

```
<Form onSubmit={(event) => this.state.id ? this.handleUpdate(this.state.id, event) : this.handleSubmit}>
```

Comment: thanks man, it made a progress for now, button's condition is working well, but the input fields in modal are not populated anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform showModal in edit mode, you can set the state based on the data you are getting from an API.